# List Search Returning No Results on Person or Group Column

Tags: list, search

A bit befuddled here, hoping someone has encountered this before...

My SharePoint 2013 custom list is not returning any results when searching it for a name in a Person or Group (single selection) column. List search for all other columns is working, and the person or group column is indexed. The list view threshold is not exceeded - we're just shy of 4,500 entries. Searching person or group columns on other lists on the site is working.

The filter on this column works so I have the team using that as a temporary workaround, but it's slower than search and I'd like to get that function back up and running.

Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for raising this. Could you tell me where to find this 'searchable' box? Still trying to get my head around Search/Managed properties and crawled properties. Thanks! Asher

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the Managed Property mapped to my Crawled Property for this column had an unchecked "Searchable" box. Checked it, ran a full crawl, and now the list search is working like a charm. #themoreyouknow!